# Unknown encoder 'libmp3lame'

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mp3, ffmpeg

I'm using ffmpeg to convert my files but when I tried to convert WAV -> MP3 I got this error.
It's surprising for me cause I installed this one yesterday.
What could happen?

Comment: I take it that you're on Linux and that libmp3lame is located someplace on the path?

Comment: I installed it from USoftwareCenter

Comment: What do you mean by "installed this one". ffmpeg or libmp3lame ?

Comment: these two by URespository

Answer (score 3):

Try installing `libavcodec-extra-52`, `libavcodec-extra-53` or `libavcodec-extra-54`:

```
sudo apt-get install libavcodec-extra-52
sudo apt-get install libavcodec-extra-53
sudo apt-get install libavcodec-extra-54
```

Answer (score 0):

libmp3lame is not part of the stock ffmpeg on Ubuntu.

What you want to do is [compile ffmpeg from source](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu) so it includes libmp3lame. They tell you how to make your ffmpeg with more option on this page. The particular item you want is `--enable-libmp3lame`.