# Unknown encoder 'libmp3lame' in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ffmpeg, mp3, ubuntu-14.04

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS. The question looks like this [Unknown encoder 'libmp3lame'](https://superuser.com/questions/205448/unknown-encoder-libmp3lame), but I followed everything there and installed every package they mentioned but still I am getting the error.

I am trying to convert FLAC to MP3 using ffmpeg, with below command:

```
ffmpeg -i hang_drum.flac -acodec libmp3lame destination_path.mp3
```

Error:

```
ffmpeg version 2.3.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
 built on Sep  5 2014 17:58:33 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
  configuration: 
  libavutil      52. 92.100 / 52. 92.100
  libavcodec     55. 69.100 / 55. 69.100
  libavformat    55. 48.100 / 55. 48.100
  libavdevice    55. 13.102 / 55. 13.102
  libavfilter     4. 11.100 /  4. 11.100
  libswscale      2.  6.100 /  2.  6.100
  libswresample   0. 19.100 /  0. 19.100
Input #0, flac, from 'hang_drum.flac':
  Metadata:
    TSS             : Logic 10.0.6
    ENCODER         : Lavf55.44.100
  Duration: 00:02:36.06, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 627 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: flac, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16
```

I tried:

- `sudo apt-get install ffmpeg libavcodec-extra-53`
- `sudo apt-get install ffmpeg libavcodec-extra-54`
- `sudo apt-get install libmp3lame0`
- `sudo apt-get install libav-tools:i386`
- `sudo apt-get install ffmpeg libav-tools`

After running these, I'm still getting the same error `libmp3lame`. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu does not officially bundle ffmpeg after ditching it in favor of the Libav fork. There is [a PPA](https://launchpad.net/~jon-severinsson/+archive/ubuntu/ffmpeg) that is quite outdated, so it should not be used unless you're keen on running an old version of ffmpeg.

I honestly have to confess that I don't know why it won't work for your specific case—or how you got an `ffmpeg` running in the first place, since Ubuntu does not bundle it officially.

Here are two solutions that should always work though:

#### Use a static build

A quick solution would be to simply [download a recent static build](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html#LinuxBuilds) (scroll down where it says *Linux Static Builds*). These all have libmp3lame bundled. Extract that build to some location, and copy `ffmpeg` to a directory in your PATH, e.g.:

```
cd ~/Downloads
tar xvf ffmpeg-*.tar.xz
cd !$
sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/bin
sudo cp ./ffmpeg ./ffprobe /usr/local/bin/
sudo chmod ugo+x /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg /usr/local/bin/ffprobe
```

Also make sure that `/usr/local/bin` is in your shell `PATH`.

#### Compile from source

This will also give you the latest version with all extras you want.  Follow the [always up-to-date guide on the FFmpeg wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu). It'll take a bit longer, but gives you more configuration options, and access to other encoders, such as libfdk_aac, which cannot be statically bundled due to licensing reasons.

Comment: Oh.. Thanks. I followed the second option and oh ! i made a mistake i think. I didn't removed ffmpeg before, looks like two ffmpag in my system. when i run `/home/ri/bin/ffmpeg -t 20 -i hang_drum.flac -acodec libmp3lame flactest20.mp3` it's works but when i remove `/home/ri/bin` in the command then it's not working.. ! can you tell me how to fix this ?

Comment: You need to change your PATH in your Bash profile (`.bash_profile`) and add `export PATH="/home/ri/bin:$PATH"`,  then reload the shell and it should use the new ffmpeg first.

Answer (score 4):

## The problem

It appears that you compiled `ffmpeg`, but you omitted the configure option `--enable-libmp3lame` which is required to be able to encode MP3 audio (there is also `--enable-libshine`, but that's a fixed-point MP3 encoder that most users won't need).

Additionally you'll need the `libmp3lame-dev` package as a dependency before compiling. Currently this needs to provide LAME ≥ 3.98.3, so if your package is too old then you can also compile LAME instead.

## How to fix

You have 3 main options if you want to use FFmpeg:

### Compile

As mentioned above you will need the LAME dependencies and use the `--enable-libmp3lame` configure option. See the [Ubuntu FFmpeg Compile Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu) for step-by-step instructions.

### Download

You can simply download, extract, and run a [static build of `ffmpeg`](http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/). It has MP3 encoding enabled.

### PPA

Ubuntu 14.04 users can utilize [mc3man's Ubuntu Multimedia for Trusty](https://launchpad.net/~mc3man/+archive/ubuntu/trusty-media). It also supports MP3 encoding.

Comment: Similar answer to slhck's, but I wanted to mention required compilation stuff and mc3man's PPA.

Comment: ok .. firstly time i don't know libmp3lame important for my project then later .... And the static build of ffmpeg sounds good . i ll try that.. And your answer very good to me bcse i am on the way to install ffmpeg in google appengine. Any guide about that ..?

Comment: @rajasimon Sorry, I've never heard of Google Appengine.